# How to store temporary metadata for the remainder of a request?

Tags: 8, routes

I am looking for a way to store some additional metadata for the remainder of a request, that should be removed after the request has finished. Sessions or SharedTempStore store persistent data across requests, which is not desirable.

The main problem is that I am working on an inbound PathProcessor, which after some path modifications needs to check if a valid path remains by using  `\Drupal::service('path.validator')->isValid($path)`. This in turn calls all PathProcessors again, leading to infinite processing. I wish to store some sort of metadata in the request, so that the PathProcessor is aware that it is ran for a second time and does nothing.

Obviously, for subsequent requests the metadata should initially be empty again so that the processing is done for each request.

Comment: It seems you are looking for the Drupal 8, class/service, equivalent of `drupal_static()`.

Comment: @kiamlaluno would you believe that in the past week it never occurred to me to use a private variable within the class. Your comment pushed me in the right direction. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, because a PathProcessor is a service class, which is in Drupal by default instantiated only once (as singleton) and so private properties persists during the remainder of a request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal introduced the [`Drupal\Core\Cache\MemoryCache\MemoryCache`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Cache%21MemoryCache%21MemoryCache.php/class/MemoryCache/8.8.x) class to, as [Added memory cache](https://www.drupal.org/node/2973262) says, allow classes that would previously maintain state on a protected property (as a static cache to avoid persistent cache or database lookups) to inject a service to hold that state instead.

Drupal core implements two services that use that class, one of them is the [*entity.memory_cache*](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/entity.memory_cache/8.8.x) service, which is defined from the following code.

```
entity.memory_cache:
  class: Drupal\Core\Cache\MemoryCache\MemoryCache
```

The other service using that class is the [*cache.jsonapi_memory*](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21jsonapi%21jsonapi.services.yml/service/cache.jsonapi_memory/8.8.x) service, which is defined from the following code.

```
cache.jsonapi_memory:
  class: Drupal\Core\Cache\MemoryCache\MemoryCache
  public: false
```

A module that needs to store data that is valid only for the current request can define a similar service. Setting the service as private is optional, but it avoids other modules uses it, making the stored data private for the module.

Comment: I believe this to be a good answer to the initial question, but IMO this added complexity only makes sense when the caches need to be invalidated from outside the class. For now I think I'll stick with my private variable :)

Comment: Like with `drupal_static()`, it should be used only when another class/function needs to reset its value, or change its value. It's not that every class property should be replaced from an instance of `MemoryCache`.